# In a MIPS assembly `addi` instruction, how is a hexadecimal immediate interpreted?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, spim, immediate-operand

Is there is a standard or recommendation for how the `addi` instruction (and others) should be interpreted in assembly, when hexadecimal immediate values are used?

Example:

```
addi $t0, $zero, 0xffff
```

I was expecting this to mean the same as `addi $t0, $zero, -1` where `0xffff` would be sign extended to `0xffffffff`, as is done by the processor, but was surprised by the fact that the assembler of the Mars simulator interprets hexadecimals as 32bit unsigned numbers and tries to do `addi $t0, $zero, 0x0000ffff` as a pseudo-instruction (if pseudo-instructions are enabled).

To be clear, MARS's assembler assembles that `addi $t0, $zero, 0xffff` pseudo-instruction to multiple machine instructions which create that constant (65535 = 0xffff) in a register and then add it, if pseudo-instructions are enabled.  MARS's simulator *simulates* instructions like `0x2008ffff` (`addi $t0, $zero, -1`) correctly.

The SPIM assembler just aborts with an error.

What I would like to know is if assemblers always interpret this way, and if there is someplace where this is written or explained as I could not find anything.

Comment: Assemblers usually interpret hexadecimal immediates as unsigned constants.

Comment: This is why there is a `subi` instruction.

Comment: @markgz There is no `subi` instruction in MIPS.

Comment: Whoops! My memory failed on that one.

Comment: That would seem to be a simulator bug -- the MIPS instruction set spec is clear that the addi instruction sign-extends the 16-bit immediate in the instruction.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: That's not a bug.  `0xffff` is not representable as a 16-bit sign-extended integer, and asm source normally uses full 32-bit constants like `-1`, not just the bit-pattern for the immediate.  What's surprising to me is that `clang -target mips` assembles it to `0x2008ffff` (i.e. `addi $t0, $zero, -1`) without even a warning about the value not fitting in an immediate, like NASM does for `add rcx, 0xffffffff`, the equivalent situation for x86-64 with 64-bit add of a 32-bit immediate.  : `warning: signed dword value exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]`

Comment: 0xFFFF != 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: There are several assemblers for MIPS, so it depends on the assembler.