# MIPS assembly `addi` instruction, how is a hexadecimal immediate interpreted?

Tags: assembly, mips, immediate-operand

there is a difference between those two instructions?
addI $12,$1,0x0000ffff
vs
addI $12,$1,0xffff

I need to know what is the value of
$12 after those instruction :

```
lui $1,0xffffff00
addi $12,$1,0x0000ffff
```

should i treat 0x0000ffff as sign extended - 0xfffffffff
or as it is - 0x0000ffff
and then $12 is 0xff00fffff ?
thanks

Comment: Try it yourself and notice the assembler warning or error about the value not being representable as a 16-bit sign-extended immediate.  (Or with MARS extended pseudo-instructions, using multiple instructions to materialize `0x0000ffff` in a register to add with that.)  Asm source uses values, not bit-patterns for immediates.

Comment: Related: [andi vs. addi instruction in MIPS with negative immediate constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40090168) / [Why is MARS mips 32 bit immediate possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42798624).  Looks like a duplicate of [In a MIPS assembly \`addi\` instruction, how is a hexadecimal immediate interpreted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37159516) which was only answered in comments.  Also [Range of immediates in lui instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53467887)

Comment: This is a question of interpretation of syntax rather than of instruction set, therefore it is a question of what the assembler does, and as there are several MIPS assemblers, so the answers can vary.

Comment: Unfortunately it depends entirely on the assembler.